# Вывод строки в Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms, индексы

Задача в следующем, дана таблица со столбцами названия, цены и веса блюд. Нужно вывести название самого дорого блюда в соотношении (цена/вес), вывод осуществляется через компонент DataGridView. Проблема вывода в том, что индекс всегда находится вне границ "массива" :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Маленькая просьба, когда пишите многоурневые условные операторы, используйте скобочики (а лучше их использовать всегда), читать подобную конструкцию...... Больно)
А по существу

```
int max_index = -1;

if(foods[i].DishWeight>food[max_index].DishWeight);
```

Учитывая что этот иф относится к else от max_index==0 (ага, когда адекватному чтению кода мешает даже форматирование)), то при первом тике срабатывает именно эта проверка. Но я не думаю что у вас есть блюдо с индексом -1)